# Cucumber and Capybara require different Selenium-Webdriver gem versions - trying to set up test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am relatively new to BDD and have been struggling to get my test environment set up and stable, and a lot of googling has still failed to surface how to solve this problem.

Capybara v 1.0.0 requires selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)

Cucumber however throws an error message when I have gem selenium-webdriver v.2.3.0 installed and demands "Could not find selenium-webdriver (~> 0.2.0)"

Is there a simple way to fix these dependencies and make selenium capybara and cucumber all play nice together?

Using cucumber (1.0.2) 
Using cucumber-rails (0.4.1)

Comment: I'm just adding a comment for anyone who comes late to this issue... it's a bit more complex than that I have discovered... there's a mess of dependencies on versions with the different testing tools... selenium and cucumber and capybara are a bit tricky to get working together :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `cucumber-rails` gem is out of date. Your version is 0.4.1 when the latest is 1.0.2. Run `bundle update cucumber-rails` to update that and try again.

Comment: Grr... flip, if it's something as obvious as that I am going to bloody kick myself!

Comment: Yup, you know I was convinced I'd tried every combo of versions between the gems but I had missed that... thanks a lot :-)